# PC sometimes stops responding after startup

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, freeze

Here's what has been happening: So I boot up my computer, then log in. Then I go to open an application, it opens fine, then starts to lag a little bit, (say I open chrome, it keeps loading the webpage in the corner of the tab, and the extensions in the corner failed to load). It says it's loading, then I try to open another program, like Task Manager. The window pops up, but none of the UI appears.

Then I go to the desktop and right click. The desktop then freezes. This just keeps going, until the only thing that responds is the mouse cursor. I tried doing Ctrl+Alt+Delete, then sign out, but it just kept on loading, saying "Signing Out"

This happened to me two or three times to me so far. The computer is a few months old, and this problem popped up a few weeks ago. It doesn't happen always, just sometimes. The only way to get out of it is to do a five-second shutdown (which I dislike doing because I have an SSD, and it then goes through this whole procedure when I start the PC up again. I'm pretty sure it's bad for the SSD)

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 5000, with an i7.

What's going on? How can I stop this? What part could be causing a problem like this? Or is it software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a new Dell, ask them - they should sort it for you. Check out your warranty. I wouldn't worry about the SSD. They last much better than early fears suggested

Comment: Yeah, I was going to contact them, but I wanted to know if anyone else had some ideas about what's going on... Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Thanks @skillz21 I know what you mean, I always want to know what's going on too